# CSS image swap animated on "mouseenter" and "mouseleave"

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I am trying to make something, and I started reading about jQuery just yesterday, so it doesnt go well for me yet :)

However what I am trying to make is to swap the image of my logo on mouseenter/leave or hover depends on whats better...

So here is what I made and it's definetly bad but ...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var logo = $('#logo');

    logo.on('mouseenter', function() {
        logo.css('background-image', 'url("img/logo2.png")');
    });
    logo.on('mouseleave', function() {
        logo.css('background-image', 'url("img/logo.png")');
    });
});
```

This works fine, it's probably not great code either... but theres no animation like fadeIn and fadeOut... I don't know how to make it.

Help me to make this please and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fade in the image you will have to load both images to begin with, one on top of the other with absolute positioning and appropriate z-index.

Then you just have to make the image 'on-top' fade-out when you hover over it, to reveal the one underneath. So you never actually have to adjust the background-image of the element.

```
<div id="logo-container" style="position:relative;">
    <div id="logo-above" style="position:absolute;z-index:2">
        <img src="img/logo1.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1">
        <img src="img/logo2.png" />
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $logoContainer = $('#logo-container');
        var $logoAbove = $('#logo-above');

        $logoContainer.on('mouseenter', function() {
            $logoAbove.fadeOut();
        });
        $logoContainer.on('mouseleave', function() {
            $logoAbove.fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

p.s. its good practice to prefix variables that are 'jqueryfied' with $ so you know not to call jquery on them again. eg `$logoContainer`.

Comment: I'm going to try this one. Thanks Nick.

Comment: Works like a charm... Just like I wanted. Thank you Nick!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/CSS_transitions) to cross-fade.  Just add the -vendor-transition properties as CSS:

```
#logo
{ 
    background: url('img/logo.png');
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6tbLp/5/)

Comment: yeh I thought of this choice as well, but I like to bug things up :) 
So if you hover many times over the image in your sample or my logo, sometimes it will not ease in or not ease out... to bad but its good tho.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xVfQx/4/).

Instead of editing one image's CSS, this technique changes the layering of two images.

Here's the JS:

```
var $img1 = $('#image1'),
    $img2 = $('#image2');

$('#logo').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $img1.stop(true, true).prependTo(this).show();
    $img2.fadeOut();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $img2.stop(true, true).prependTo(this).show();
    $img1.fadeOut();
});​
```

Comment: Well, I tried this one right now. As I mentioned I like to bug things up and this method leaves the image on fadeOut if you hover in/out many times. Try ... :) 

Thanks for post. It's working but buggy for me :(

Comment: @NenaddvL Fixed the issue. Now the animation is stopped if interrupted. Hover as fast as you'd like!